# Unable to set cursor in Draft.js editor

Tags: draftjs

I am trying to integrate the Draft.js editor in a project.
The way I am thinking of using it, is to create a new EditorState out of my own state on every render call (the reason for this approach are related to my specific context I am not going to detail here).

What I have not succeeded is to set the cursor position in the Editor.

I have created an example on Codepen: 
    http://codepen.io/nutrina/pen/JKaaOo?editors=0011

In this example any character I type is prepended to the beginning of the text, instead of being inserted at the cursor position.
I have tried setting the cursor by using:

```
  state = EditorState.acceptSelection(state, this.state.selectionState);
  state = EditorState.forceSelection(state, this.state.selectionState);
```

but without much success.
Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Gerald

Comment: I happened answer the same question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38749474/losing-the-selection-after-a-mutation

Comment: @JiangYD: Thanks for the hint, I am a step further now. In my case however the keys remain unchanged. I am basically restoring the selection state of the editor on each render, but now the cursor advances 2 positions? I have updated the Codepen sample. Any ideas?

Comment: I suppose that some key press triggers multiple 'onChange' events, but your code break the events by generating a new EditorState, then something happens weirdly. 'create a new EditorState  every render call' will not work I think. Maybe you could set a EditorState in component state for selection change rendering, and use your 'new state' for content change rendering.

Answer (score 0):

A easy way to move the cursor around is to use [Editor.forceSelection](https://draftjs.org/docs/api-reference-editor-state#forceselection) and a [key binding function](https://draftjs.org/docs/advanced-topics-key-bindings.html)!

This is what your render function would look like once you have it set up

```
render() {
    return (
      <Editor
        editorState={this.state.editorState}
        onChange={this.onChange}
        handleKeyCommand={this.handleKeyCommand}
        keyBindingFn={this.myKeyBindingFn}
      />
    );
  }
```

Once you have your keybinding function, you can do something along the lines of

```
  myKeyBindingFn = (e) => {
    // on spacebar
    if (e.keyCode == 32) {
      const newSelection = selectionState.merge({
        anchorOffset: selectionState.getAnchorOffset() + 1,
        focusOffset: selectionState.getAnchorOffset() + 1,
      });

      const newEditorState = EditorState.forceSelection(
        editorState,
        newSelection,
      );

      this.setState({ editorState: newEditorState });

      return 'space-press';
    }
  };
```

Feel free to replace `anchorOffset` and `focusOffset` with the position you would like the cursor to be in. Using a keybinding function allows better control over events

Your handleKeyCommand function would look something like this

```
handleKeyCommand = (command: string): DraftHandleValue => {
    if (command === 'space-press') {
      return 'handled';
    }
    return 'not-handled';
  };
```